# Using Dropbox Datastore API as a primary storage option for Android application

Tags: dropbox-api, datastore

I'm looking for a way to sync SQLite data of my Android app across devices.

Dropbox Datastore API seems to fit just fine (at least conceptually). I've studied available [examples](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/datastore), but cannot yet understand how does this API fit into Android data access worldview with it's ContentProvider=>ContentResolver=>Adaptor=>ListView machinery.

My guess is that certain plumbing is required for smoother integration of Datastore API, maybe even as a drop-in replacement of SQLite. And the best place where it belongs seems to be close to ContentProvider.

Is the above assumption correct, i.e.: should i try to write my custom ContentProvider that will take it's data from Datastore API? Or maybe better options exist/planned?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't (yet) an existing infrastructure/library for directly connecting Dropbox Datastores to SQLite or Android Content Providers.  But conceptually, I think you have the right layering in mind.  A Datastore provides a similar sort of functionality to SQLite, so you can fit it into your application at the same layer.  A ContentProvider built on top of a Dropbox Datastore would be a good way to abstract away the details and fit in with a lot of existing Android functionality.  It should be relatively straightforward to adapt for simple queries.