# Search through dropbox files using their API

Tags: android, dropbox

Is there a way to search through a dropbox account to find a file with your own app using their API.

For example I want to find all *.jpg in my drop box account from my app.  or all files containing the word 'smile' in the title. etc.

I have been searching but either its not provided or i'm not searching with the right terms.

Comment: Possible dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17725422/using-dropbox-datastore-api-as-a-primary-storage-option-for-android-application

Comment: @DavidCowden I think it's not a duplicate. _Using Dropbox Datastore API as a primary storage option_ it's not the same as this question

Comment: But read the answer.  There is no dropbox content provider thus, despite the fact that you phrased your question in a slightly different way, you're effectively asking the same thing.  But you're right, they are two different questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried the full core REST API? I found this in their documentation: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs#search.

It looks like you can search the way you want using that API. I have never used the dropbox API, but figured I'd help if I can. Hope it helps!

Comment: This may be it.  Is this something I could embed from a separate android app without prompting for a drop box log in each time?  Thus that if i had an app that could search my box and dropbox acounts for me so i can find where i put that image i'm looking for. etc.

Comment: I am not very sure about the Dropbox API as I have never used it, but it seems like it supports OAuth-style authentication. You will need to make the user login at least once. There's usually a period of time you can then remain "logged in" on behalf of the user and perform the search REST API requests in your application.